mi macro de excel sobreescribe nuevos datos, en celdas que contienen datos anteriores, como podría resolverlo?
mi macro de excel esta sobreescribendo los datos nuevos que se ingresan y los ingresa en las celdas que ya tenian datos anteriores, he estado investigando y me gustaria saber si podrian ayudarme, aca les muestro el codigo del formulario de excel para añadir nuevos datos:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

desproteger_hoja

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Reporte Comercial").Select

Range("A4").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

linea_fin = ActiveCell.Row

Range("B" & linea_fin) = UCase(Lb_Year)
Range("C" & linea_fin) = Lb_Month
Range("E" & linea_fin) = Cb_Pais
Range("F" & linea_fin) = Cb_Puerto
Range("H" & linea_fin) = Txt_Barco
Range("I" & linea_fin) = Txt_Owner
Range("AZ" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id
Range("J" & linea_fin) = Cb_Tipo_Carga

Lb_Conteo = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("BB:BB"), Lb_Id)

If Val(Lb_Conteo) < 10 Then
    Lb_Conteo = "0" & Lb_Conteo
End If
    
Range("A" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id & Lb_Conteo

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla14").Resize Range("$A$4:$BB$4729" & linea_fin)

'Borrando valores en formulario
Lb_Id = ""
Lb_Year = ""
Lb_Month = ""
Lb_Fecha_Corta = ""
Cb_Pais = ""
Cb_Puerto = ""
Txt_Barco = ""
Txt_Owner = ""
Txt_Fecha = ""
Cb_Tipo_Carga = ""
Lb_Conteo = 1
Txt_Fecha.SetFocus

proteger_hoja

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Este codigo fue escrito antes que yo entrara, es un archivo que tiene 5 años, el anterior encargado no dejo nada explicado o en que consiste el codigo, De antemano gracias.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    desproteger_hoja

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Reporte Comercial")

    ' Encontrar la siguiente fila vacía en la columna A
    Dim linea_fin As Long
    linea_fin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Asignar valores a las celdas de la nueva fila
    ws.Range("B" & linea_fin) = UCase(Lb_Year)
    ws.Range("C" & linea_fin) = Lb_Month
    ws.Range("E" & linea_fin) = Cb_Pais
    ws.Range("F" & linea_fin) = Cb_Puerto
    ws.Range("H" & linea_fin) = Txt_Barco
    ws.Range("I" & linea_fin) = Txt_Owner
    ws.Range("AZ" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id
    ws.Range("J" & linea_fin) = Cb_Tipo_Carga

    ' Contar ocurrencias de Lb_Id en la columna BB
    Lb_Conteo = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("BB:BB"), Lb_Id)

    ' Formatear el conteo si es menor que 10
    If Val(Lb_Conteo) < 10 Then
        Lb_Conteo = "0" & Lb_Conteo
    End If

    ' Asignar el valor a la columna A
    ws.Range("A" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id & Lb_Conteo

    ' Redimensionar la tabla
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla14").Resize ws.Range("$A$4:$BB$4729")

    ' Borrar valores en el formulario
    Lb_Id = ""
    Lb_Year = ""
    Lb_Month = ""
    Lb_Fecha_Corta = ""
    Cb_Pais = ""
    Cb_Puerto = ""
    Txt_Barco = ""
    Txt_Owner = ""
    Txt_Fecha = ""
    Cb_Tipo_Carga = ""
    Lb_Conteo = 1
    Txt_Fecha.SetFocus

    proteger_hoja

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Con este cambio tu macro tiene que funcionar bien y los nuevos datos ingresaran en la siguiente fila vacia sin sobrescribir datos anteriores
Saludos

prueba esto:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim shtDatos As Worksheet

desproteger_hoja

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtDatos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reporte Comercial")
'Última fila con datos en columna B. Para que no sobreescriba datos sumas 1 y empiezas en la siguiente fila que estaará en blanco.
linea_fin = shtDatos.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

shtDatos.Range("B" & linea_fin) = UCase(Lb_Year)
shtDatos.Range("C" & linea_fin) = Lb_Month
shtDatos.Range("E" & linea_fin) = Cb_Pais
shtDatos.Range("F" & linea_fin) = Cb_Puerto
shtDatos.Range("H" & linea_fin) = Txt_Barco
shtDatos.Range("I" & linea_fin) = Txt_Owner
shtDatos.Range("AZ" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id
shtDatos.Range("J" & linea_fin) = Cb_Tipo_Carga

Lb_Conteo = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("BB:BB"), Lb_Id)

If Val(Lb_Conteo) < 10 Then
    Lb_Conteo = "0" & Lb_Conteo
End If
    
Range("A" & linea_fin) = Lb_Id & Lb_Conteo

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla14").Resize Range("$A$4:$BB$4729" & linea_fin)

'Borrando valores en formulario
Lb_Id = ""
Lb_Year = ""
Lb_Month = ""
Lb_Fecha_Corta = ""
Cb_Pais = ""
Cb_Puerto = ""
Txt_Barco = ""
Txt_Owner = ""
Txt_Fecha = ""
Cb_Tipo_Carga = ""
Lb_Conteo = 1
Txt_Fecha.SetFocus

proteger_hoja

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

